# Jetty Servlet forward jsp: forward error

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, webserver, jetty

The problem in the forward jsp
Gives an error message:

```
2016-01-27 13:22:13.192:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1132700707-25: Error for /
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.String.startsWith(String.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher$ForwardAttributes.setAttribute(Dispatcher.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1925)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:74)
    at pages.index.doGet(index.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

DoGet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/") 
public class index extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

Start Server:

```
WebAppContext webapp1 = new WebAppContext();
webapp1.setResourceBase("src/Pages");
webapp1.setContextPath("/");
webapp1.setDefaultsDescriptor("src/WEB-INF/web.xml");
webapp1.setDescriptor("src/WEB-INF/web.xml");
server.setHandler(webapp1);
```

*getServletContext()*
does not help

Please help me understand what the problem is.

Added index.jsp, generate NetBeans 8.1,  i not change.:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1><h:outputText value="Hello World!"/></h1>
        </body>
    </html>
</f:view>
```

Comment: http://i10.pixs.ru/storage/0/0/3/Untitledpn_1337298_20424003.png

Comment: default generate jsp NetBeans

Comment: Can you view index.jsp from browser without forwarding?

Comment: Yes...if using weappcontext or doGet print writter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that your `index.jsp` is calling servlet, and servlet is calling `index.jsp` so they have infinite loop. Change the page servlet should forward

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did do the

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

as suggested by Roman C. However that didn't solve it alone. I also removed all servlet mappings.